# RANKX not working due to "Single value for column XX in table YY cannot be determined"

Tags: powerbi, cumulative-sum

I am attempting to insert a column that continuously sums up all values from another column (here values from GrossMargeEUR) beginning with the largest down to the smallest value. [image: It should look like this example here] In order to accomplish that I found a video that appears to be offering the solution to my problem:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5k4fD1YJrQ&ab_channel=EnterpriseDNA

However, I am unable to replicate this solution due to RANKX not being applicable in my example. Creating a measure with RANKX triggers the error message

> A single value for column 'GrossMargeEUR' in table 'Table1' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.

[image: Screenshot of my current table with the error message]

I am uncertain what this message means as there are no values missing in my first column. Why is it not possible to introduce a proper ranking here that can then be used to create a cumulalative sum column? Can anyone help here, please?

Comment: You have 2 mistakes in your formula. First, gross margin must be a measure, not a column. Write a simple measure that sums up your gross margin column, and then use it. Second, you need to use ALL(Table1) instead of just table1.

Comment: That's where I have originally started - RANKX as a measure - but I read somewhere that it needs to be a column in order to address the error message (see https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/using-rankx-in-computed-column-and-measure#:~:text=Using%20RANKX%20in%20MEASURE&text=%E2%80%9CA%20single%20value%20for%20column,to%20get%20a%20single%20result.%E2%80%9D).

However, having modified my formula according to your input, it still results in the same error message and I am not even able to add it to my table:
https://ibb.co/844nSqv

Comment: You misunderstood my comment. Instead of Table1[GrossMargeEUR], you must create a measure (for example, Gross Margin = SUM( Table1[GrossMargeEUR]), and use it inside RANX formula.

Comment: oh, got it. and it is finally displaying the correct ranking. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: actually, there's one further question that I have. When applying your formula (where Measure_GM = SUM( Table1[GrossMargeEUR])), I get several doublicate values such as rank number 9 and 21. Do you know what my mistake is here?

https://ibb.co/w6Xf6xm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RANKX function expects the following:

```
RANKX(<table>, <expression>[, <value>[, <order>[, <ties>]]])
```

You are passing a column reference instead of an expression, so first create your rank measure like this:

```
SalesRank = 
    RANKX(ALLSELECTED('Table'[Product]), 
        CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Sales])) 
        + DIVIDE (
            RANKX (
                ALLSELECTED ( 'Table'[Product] ),
                    CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Table'[Product] ) ),
                    ,DESC,DENSE
            ),
            100),,DESC)
```

The `+ DIVIDE` is there to break ties when 2 products have had the same sales.

Once you have the measure above, you can calculate your cumulative total like this:

```
Cumulative = 
  VAR crank = [SalesRank]
  RETURN SUMX(
      FILTER(
      SUMMARIZE(
          ALLSELECTED('Table'[Product]),
          'Table'[Product],
          "sales", SUM('Table'[TotalSales]),
          "rank", [SalesRank]
      ), [rank] <= crank), [sales])
```

So you save the rank for that product in a variable, then use the `SUMX` with a calculated table which contains all the products up to that rank.

[image]

Comment: thank you! It took me a while to build up a better understanding of Dax (I am pretty much at the beginning) but I was now able to successfully apply your example. Instead of [TotalSales], I used sum('Table'[Total Sales]) in order to get the formula to run (saying this so anybody that attempts to copy this solution).

Comment: That helped me for sure. I used that approach and solved major problems in my dashboard. Thanks for code @joaoleal